# I want to run a missing data code in Julia but see this error and don't why

Tags: julia, missing-data

I am new to Julia. I want to handle missing data in Julia using `replace` function. but I got this error: AbstractDataFrame is not iterable. Use eachrow(df) to get a row iterator or eachcol(df) to get a column iterator

Here is my code. it will show the time consumption for imputing missing data

```
using Missings
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(i=1:6, x=[5, missing, 4, missing, 2,1])
replace!(df.x, missing=> 10)
@time sum(skipmissing(df))
```

I don't know how to correct this error. Did I miss something in my code?

Comment: Can you describe the result you would like to obtain? It's not clear what values you want to sum.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the language and DataFrames.jl. In the latest version you can easily use `dropmissing!(df)` to remove the df for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the column name where you want to calculate the sum:

```
sum(skipmissing(df.x))
```

If you want to calculate the sum over the entire table you can do:

```
sum(sum.(skipmissing.(eachcol(df))))
```